# collecting files

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a large directory containing many subdirectories inside, in each subdirectory there are 4 different files (`C1`,`C2`,`C3`,`C4`).

What I want to do is to collect the same subdirectories but with only one file (`C1`) inside. So the point is to delete the other files (`C2`,`C3`,`C4`) and keep the same hierarchy of directories.

I want to have a simple script to do that because it´s impossible to do it manually since I have a very large main directory.
The structure of the directory of just one simple case is : sampling/time´i´/C´j´.
with i =0.0001:10 and 
     j=1:4

I have this case on cluster.

Comment: what do you mean by "collecting files" ?  It would  be better if you provide some example, sample folder structure and what you want to do with that ?

Comment: What Linux version are you using?

Comment: Acctually I am running a simulation on cluster where on each time step (t) I calculate the concentrations (C1,C2,C3,C4).So inside the main folder named <Sampling> I have many subfolders presenting the time from 0.005s to 10s and inside each subfolder (time folder)  there 4 files (C1,C2,C3,C4), What I need is how to delete the files C1,C2,C3 and keep C4 inside each time folder

Comment: THe Linux version is : CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511

Comment: these folders has only `C1..C4` or are there other files also ?

Comment: yes there are similar files but with the same extention , I just put it as exemple, but what I need really is to keep just one file of all these files (I adjusted to C4 in the exemple)

Comment: that means you want to remove other files except `C1` ?

Comment: Exactly , and keep each C1 file in its subfolder (time subfolder) because it corresponds to that time. The sampling folder (which contain the time folders ) is superlarge, I could nt even compress it

Comment: It's better if you saw us your directory structure. Please post it in your question rather than extending conversation here.

Comment: try `find . ! -name 'C1' -type f -exec echo rm -f {} +`. And if you are satisfied with the result than remove `echo`. Run this command from parent directory.

Comment: I still can not be able to solve my problem  , sorry

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Why do Rahul's and sjsam's solutions not work?

Comment: You say you are on a cluster . . . Is this a normal Linux POSIX filesystem, or something like HDFS?

Comment: What is the content of the C1 files? If it is just one line, it would probably be useful to combine all your C1 files into a single file, and then remove the entire "Sampling" directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a backup of the parent folder, say the new folder name is `parentbackup`

```
cp parent parentbackup
```

then do

```
find parentbackup -type f -not -name C1 -exec rm {} \;
```

or using regex

```
find parentbackup -type f -regex 'C[^1]' -exec rm {} \;
```

If you're allowed to modify the parent directory, then do

**Edit**

```
find /path/to/parent -type f -regex 'C[^1]' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: One could also use `cp -al` to create a shadow tree of hard links.

Comment: @Law29  : Not sure if the original directory structure could/should be modified. If so i would apply rm on the original folder itself.

Comment: I can´t just copy the directory, it is super large

Comment: @R.Bichi : Are you allowed to modify the original directory?

Comment: yes I can, it is just so large that I can´t even list its sub directories

Comment: Since you are deleting subdirectories you will need `-exec rm -rf`. Do use `-exec echo rm -rf` to check what you are going to delete before actually doing this!

Comment: no Acctually I am deleting only files inside these subdirectories (keeping just one file)

Comment: @Law29 : As per the questions directories need to be intact

Comment: Ok I can explain for the "sjsam" solution I could not copy the parent folder because it is so large (actually it´s copying but it will take sooo much time for that)
And for "Rahul´s" it worked when I want to delete the files from the subdirectory but when I want to do that from the parent directory it taking so much time and I don´t know if it´s working or not at the end